# Apache Cassandra monitoring

Tags: cassandra, monitoring

What is the best way to monitor if cassandra nodes are up? Due to security reasons JMX and nodetool is out of question. I have cluster metrics monitoring via Rest Api, but I understand that even if a node goes Rest Api will only report on a whole cluster.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have integrated a system where I can monitor all the metrics regarding to my cluster of all nodes. This seems like complicated but pretty simple to integrate. You will need the following components to build up a monitoring system for `cassandra`:

- jolokia jar
- telegraf
- influxdb
- grafana

I'm writing a short procedure, how it works.
**Step 1:** copy `jolokia jvm jar` to `install_dir/apache-cassandra-version/lib/` , jolokia jvm agent can be downloaded from anywhere in google.

**Step 2:** add the following line to `install_dir/apache-cassandra-version/conf/cassandra-env.sh`

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:<here_goes_the_path_of_your_jolokia_jar>"
```

**Step 3:** install `telegraf` on each node and configure the metrics you want to monitor. and start `telegraf` service.

**Step 4:** install `grafana` and configure your ip, port, protocol. `grafana` will give you a dashboard to look after your nodes and start `grafana` service. Your metrics will be able get visibility here.

**Step 5:** install `influxdb` on another server from where you want to store your metrics data which will come through telegraf agent.

**Step 6:** browse the ip you have mentioned, where you have launched your grafana through browser and add data source ip (influxdb ip), then customize your dashboard.

[image]
image source: https://blog.pythian.com/monitoring-cassandra-grafana-influx-db/

Comment: Most of the documentation online regarding the jolokia + Telegraf monitoring configuration for Cassandra indicates one must install both apps on each Cassandra node. Is there a way to use a dedicated EC2 instance running these two apps to connect to each Cassandra node and then output the metrics in aggregate to a sink like CloudWatch? Seems hard to maintain if you have a five-node Cassandra deployment to have to make any updates to five separate nodes rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not for monitoring but only for node state.
Cassandra CQL driver provides info if a particular node is UP or DOWN with Host.StateListener Interface. This info is used by driver to mark a node UP or Down. Thus it could be used if node is down or up if JMX is not accessible.

Java Doc API : https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.3/

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a script which listens for DN nodes in the cluster and reports it to our monitoring setup which is integrated with pagerduty.

The script runs on one of our nodes and executes nodetool status every minute and reports for all down nodes.

Here is the script https://gist.github.com/johri21/87d4d549d05c3e2162af7929058a00d1

[1]: